# filter in p:datatable does not filter instead shows nothing

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In an attempt to work on the dynamic list and dynamic html, I have built a dynamic table with dynamic columns in the data table, all is working fine and works as required except it does not filter instead it shows no record as some text is typed. ..................................

```
@ManagedBean(name="liveRangeService", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped

public class LiveRangeService implements Serializable {

    ResultSet RS;
    dbConnectionSQLServer db;

    private List< Map<String, ColumnModel> > tableData;
    private Map<String, ColumnModel> selectedData;
    private List< Map<String, ColumnModel> > filteredData;

    public Map<String, ColumnModel> getSelectedData() {
        return selectedData;
    }

    public void setSelectedData(Map<String, ColumnModel> selectedData) {
        this.selectedData = selectedData;
    }
    private List<ColumnModel> tableHeaderNames;
    private String tableColWidths;
    private List< Map<String, ColumnModel> > selectedRow;

    public List<Map<String, ColumnModel>> getTableData() {
        return tableData;
    }
    public List<ColumnModel> getTableHeaderNames() {
        return tableHeaderNames;
    }

    public LiveRangeService() {
    }

    public void LiveRangeServicesss() {
        db = new dbConnectionSQLServer();
        try {
            tableData = new ArrayList< Map<String, ColumnModel> >();
            tableHeaderNames = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();

            Statement SQL = dbConnectionSQLServer.getCN().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            RS = SQL.executeQuery("Select * From Coa32 Order BY Title");

            for (int j = 0; j < RS.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                tableHeaderNames.add(new ColumnModel("header "+j, RS.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(j+1)));
            }

            //Generate table data.
            for (int i = 0; RS.next(); i++) {
                Map<String, ColumnModel> playlist = new HashMap<String, ColumnModel>();
//                System.out.println("Row : " + i );
                for (int j = 0; j < RS.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    playlist.put(tableHeaderNames.get(j).key, new ColumnModel(tableHeaderNames.get(j).key, RS.getString(j+1)));
                }
                tableData.add(playlist);
            }
            PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:dlgTBL");
            PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:dlgTBL2");
            PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('dlg').show();");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error !!! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public List<Map<String, ColumnModel>> getSelectedRow() {
        try {System.out.println("Selected Row! " + selectedRow.size());} catch (Exception e) {}

        return selectedRow;
    }

    public void setSelectedRow(List<Map<String, ColumnModel>> selectedRow) {
        System.out.println( "selected size: " + selectedRow.size() );
        this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    }

    public String getTableColWidths() {
        return tableColWidths;
    }

    public void setTableColWidths(String tableColWidths) {
        this.tableColWidths = tableColWidths;
    }

    public List<Map<String, ColumnModel>> getFilteredData() {
        return filteredData;
    }

    public void setFilteredData(List<Map<String, ColumnModel>> filteredData) {
        this.filteredData = filteredData;
    }
}
```

Following is html portion

```
            <p:dialog id="dlgTBL" modal="true" showEffect="bounce" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
                <p:dataTable var="result" id="tbl" widgetVar="dtlTBL"
                                    value="#{liveRangeService.tableData}" 
                                    paginator="false"
                                    scrollable="true"  rowIndexVar="index"  scrollHeight="500" 
                                    scrollRows="50" liveScroll="true"
                                    filterDelay="1100"
                    >
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{indexBean.onRowSelect}"  />
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel layout="inline" styleClass="tabSpacer">
                            <h:outputText value="Global Filter:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('dtlTBL').filter()" style="width:150px;margin-left:10px;"/>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column width="10">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sr." />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:columns value="#{liveRangeService.tableHeaderNames}"
                               var="mycolHeader" 
                               width="#{colIndex==0?'10%':colIndex==1?'70%':colIndex==2?'10%':colIndex==3?'10%':'0'}" 
                               columnIndexVar="colIndex" selectRow="true"
                               sortBy="#{result[mycolHeader.value]}"
                               filterBy="#{result[mycolHeader.value]}"
                               filterMatchMode="contains"                        
                               >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mycolHeader.value}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{result[mycolHeader.key].value}" />
                        <br />
                    </p:columns>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>
```

Please advise the change in code.

Comment: I m using currently primefaces 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it's probably how you set the sortBy and filterBy attributes.

```
var="result"
```

is an instance of Map, if I'm reading this correctly.

```
"#{result[mycolHeader.value]}"
```

has a problem, where you use .value instead of .key. If you use .key, it would still return ColumnModel, if I'm not mistaken. So the way you set up the filter is that the text you put in the filter will be matched to an ColumnModel instance, should one be found from the map.

Hopefully I read the code correctly, since it was a bit confusing. Especially you using ColumnModel as a (String,String) tuple and not just it's intended purpose. I think you can change the type of tableData from

```
List<Map<String,ColumnModel>>
```

to

```
List<Map<String,String>>
```

since it doesn't seem you use both field of ColumnModel.

Comment: bundle of, thousands of thanx, it was really simple.. it worked gr8. thanx again @kozeljko